# Android studio cannot resolve ActionBarActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, symbols, resolve

I have tried invalidating the caches and restarting but it still shows up and will not compile and run as it used to before. I tried renaming the class file if i remember correctly and must have changed the name on something that made this how up. It also gives me the same error where findViewById, .oncreate, and setContentView. I migh have also renamed or tried to rename one of the packages because it was examplecom and it wouldnt allow me to upload it.

```
package com.threedeestone.mike.threedeestone;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.text.DecimalFormat;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
```

Comment: Change to `AppCompatActivity`

Comment: You have to add the appcompat library to your project. Also change to AppCompatActivity.

Comment: @Mike Stone did my answer helped to you? if it did mark it as a correct otherwise let me know and I'll try to update it.

Answer (score 4):

Check this [blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.es/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html) where explains the changes on the `Library`.

`ActionBarActivity` is deprecated, you should use `AppCompatActivity` instead and make a clear project and try it out.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
```

If the issue still it could be that in your `gradle.app` you don't have added this line of code

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
```

Answer (score 4):

To use the `ActionBarActivity` or the `AppCompatActivity` you have to add the **appcompat** library to your dependencies.

Add in your `build.gradle` file the last version:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0"
}
```

**The version 23.0.0 requires to compile the project with API 23.**
Otherwise you can use the 22.2.1.

Also pay attention.
The `ActionBarActivity` is **deprecated**. Check the [official javadoc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html).
You should use the `AppCompatActivity`.